# My UK standard visit visa application was refused for lack of intention to leave the country

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for a UK standard visit visa to the UK. I have lived legally in the UK for about 6 years while studying. I applied to extend my stay but was refused, so I appealed under article 8 of the European Convention on Human Rights, which failed. I returned to Pakistan voluntarily.

Now, after 3 years in Pakistan, I applied for a visa, but it was refused on the grounds that I would not leave the UK and that my circumstances in Pakistan are not strong enough for me to want to return.

During my earlier visa extension request appeal, the judge had stated that I have strong ties with Pakistan and I should return to my country. That is contradictory; the judge said I had strong ties but, today, the Entry Clearance Officer said that my situation is not strong, despite bank statement, family agricultural land, and my savings and accounts. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have a job in Pakistan? Dependents? Family agricultural land that’s not held in your name may count for little. If you post a copy of your refusal letter with personal details blanked out you may get better answers, but on the face of it with your history your best option is to consult an immigration lawyer if you are intent on visiting the U.K. again. Or wait a few years longer and build up a travel history meanwhile.

Comment: Those are part of the vicissitudes and inconsistencies in the immigration/visa process due to the human element. It is a judgment call many times, one immigration officer would see things one way, the other would see it a different way. Your best advice at this point is to get an immigration solicitor. Your case is not the norm being that you previously have lived in the UK and were asked to leave. Applying on your own will almost certainly lead to another prompt refusal.

Comment: Not really a duplicate. I suspect the grounds given arise from the OP's history of appeals rather than his ties, or lack of, to Pakistan.

Answer (score 21):

In the past you've applied to extend your stay in the UK, to the extent that you invoked a court case under article 8 of the [European Convention on Human Rights](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Convention_on_Human_Rights). This has marked you as someone **very** keen to stay in the UK, and thus at a high risk of going underground if you're allowed to visit again. I'd be very surprised if you can get a visa in the next few years.

What you should do is clear: consult a lawyer with expertise in UK immigration.

This may seem an abrupt answer but your case is far too complex for strangers on the internet to be able to contribute meaningfully.

Good luck!

Comment: This is not an abrupt answer. This is ***the*** answer.